# How to save in a .txt file with Spring boot?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

I need to create a REST api that saves the names in a .txt file and that I can retrieve them when I needed. Below I have the code. I'm using the spring boot framework.

My REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/people", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> escreverArquivo() throws Exception {

    String line = "";
    try {
        File file = new File("nomes.txt");

        // Se o arquivo nao existir, ele gera
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        // Escreve e fecha arquivo
        bw.write(line);
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(line, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/pessoas", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> lerArquivo() throws Exception {

    String line = null;
    try {
        FileReader ler = new FileReader("nomes.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(ler);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(line, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The first method does not add anything that is not within the string line, the second method does not show anything on the screen, only in the sts console.

Comment: Why a text file instead of a database?

Comment: *"saves the names"* What names? In `escreverArquivo`, you initialize `lines` to an empty string, then write it to the file (i.e. writing nothing), then return it as a response entity (i.e. returning an empty string). What's the point of that? Also, the method handles a POST request, but you don't accept any posted data, so why is it a POST, if there is no data? Re-think what you're doing, e.g. the POST should have data (is that the names you mentioned), so you need to accept that data and perhaps make it go into the `lines` variable, or whatever it is you were trying to do with that one?

Comment: chrylis, the test requires a .txt file instead of a database

Comment: Andreas, the names are typed on the "site" screen, in a form, i'm a little lost, so there are so many confusing things in the code

Comment: You stored neither payload nor request parameters into any object, what you want to write into file?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a text file for storing any data you want to keep for any amount of time. They are not a reliable way of storing data, particularly as the load on your api increases.

You mention in a comment that your test requires a text file, but you should consider whether this is a good idea or not. Your tests should test the **behaviour** of your code, not the **implementation**. The tests should be happy with any code that makes `saveName()` and `getNames()` (or equivalent functions) behave as expected.

It is really worth getting comfortable with the basics of Java first before trying to use something like Spring Boot.

However, if you are really desperate to save a string to a text file, the Apache Commons IO library provides several nice helper methods, most notably:

`FileUtils.write(new File("myFile.txt"), "Content Text", "UTF-8");`

However, I strongly urge you to consider whether you **really** want a text file that is unencrypted, non-reduntant, easily corruptible, and likely not backed-up to store important data.

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the POST data and initialize the line String with it. Something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/people", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
    public String escreverArquivo(@RequestParam(value="nomeDaPessoa") String nomeDaPessoa) throws Exception {
        String line = nomeDaPessoa;

        // ...
    }
```

Note that you should replace nomeDaPessoa with the name of the field coming from your Form.